# Comparing data in different columns via VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, list, excel, comparison

First topic here after reading many, solving many doubts and opening my mind! Thanks everyone for this hahaha

I found many topics about how to compare numbers/texts/etc between 2 columns, either by macro or formula.
My problem is that I will have an undefined number of columns with different number of lines.

Each column stands for one list of codes, that are in the format as this sheet:

```
List 1  List 2  List 3  List 4
1A      1A      1B      1B
3F      3F      3F      3F
8B      8B      8B      8B
10B     10B     10B     10B
11A     11A     11A     11A
14Q     14Q     14Q     14Q
17TX    17TX    17TX    17TX
20A     20A     20C     20C
21BM    21BM    21BM    21BM
22AX    22AX    22AX    22AX
24A     24A     25C     25C
```

Here comes the problem: these numbers go up to 6500, the letters can have many combinations.

I need to compare and have results for:
- first to second, third and fourth
- then second to third and fourth
- then third to fourth.

Here comes another problem: I can have two of these lists and I can have 90 of these lists. There is no precise number.

I can't use conditional formatting to highlight unique or duplicate values because I can have 4 lists, being first=second and third=fourth, that wouldn't highlight anything. This would only work if the maximum was 3.

1=2 and 3=4=5 would result the same, and so on.

I used this code to create a loop, but it already takes too long to compare two lists, for many it would take the whole day:

```
Sub LOOPING()
    colunavazia = Sheets("Ref").Cells(1, 1) + 2
    ActiveSheet.Cells(2, colunavazia).Select

    linha_1 = 2
    linha_2 = 2
    coluna_1 = 1
    coluna_2 = 2
    coluna_3 = colunavazia

    While Cells(1, coluna_2) <> ""
        While ActiveSheet.Cells(linha_1, coluna_1) <> ""
            While ActiveSheet.Cells(linha_2, coluna_1) <> ""
                If ActiveSheet.Cells(linha_1, coluna_1) = Sheet2.Cells(linha_2, coluna_2) Then
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(linha_2, coluna_3) = "OK"
                        Else
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(linha_2, coluna_3) = "NOOOOOOO"
                End If
                linha_2 = linha_2 + 1
            Wend
            linha_2 = 2
            linha_1 = linha_1 + 1
        Wend
        linha_1 = 2
        linha_2 = 2
        coluna_1 = 1
        coluna_2 = coluna_2 + 1
        coluna_3 = coluna_3 + 1
    Wend
```

It searches the code of line 1 on first column in the whole second column and returns OK if true. That would be a good idea if it didn't take like forever to show the results.

Do anyone have any other suggestion? Thanks from now!

Comment: If you used `For` loops you could use `Exit For` to shorten the execution time greatly.

Comment: Never used "for" to loop. How would it be?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html) out.

Comment: Wait what exactly is the desired result here?

Comment: Nice Mr Mascaro, I'll check it out!

Comment: chancea, show how many different columns I have

Comment: So you want another column with a numeric value of the unique number of values pertaining to that row?  or are you saying just _one_ value all together?

Comment: Something that says "list 1 = list 2, list 3 = list 4", or anything near this

Comment: Ok, I did it with the "For". I'll post the code later, but to clarify:

- it compares the first list, checking if the first cell is equal to any other cell in list 2, and to this to all other rows in list 1
- after it's ok, it starts again with the second, comparing to all in front of it (e.g. if 5 lists, compare 2 with 3, 4 and 5)

Now I'm working on a way to skip to start comparison between equal lists (e.g. if list 1 = list 2, it's not necessary to compare list 2 with 3, 4 and 5)

is it confusing or am I clear?

Answer (score 0):

Well, managed to do it after a couple hours trying. Thanks for the suggestions!

```
    ref = Sheets("Ref").Cells(1, 1)

    cres = ref + 5

    lformula = 2
    cformula = ref + 2
    cformulacomp = ref + 3

    For cref = 1 To ref
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, cref).End(xlUp).Row
    For ccomp = cref + 1 To ref

    For lref = 2 To lastrow 'substituir por 5 para testes / lastrow para solução final

    For lcomp = 2 To lastrow 'substituir por 5 para testes / lastrow para solução final

    If ActiveSheet.Cells(1, cres) = "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, cres).Value = cref & " x " & ccomp
    lformula = lformula + 1
    End If

    If Cells(lref, cref) = Cells(lcomp, ccomp) Then
    Cells(lref, cres) = "OK"
    End If

    Next lcomp


    Next lref

    If ActiveSheet.Cells(lformula, cformula) = "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(lformula, cformula).Value = cref & " x " & ccomp
    Cells(lformula, cformula + 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(COUNTA(R2C" & cref & ":R1200C" & cref & ")=COUNTIF(R2C" & cres & ":R1200C" & cres & ",""OK""),""Iguais"",""Diferentes"")" 'Trocar R5C por R1200C

    End If

    cres = cres + 1

    Next ccomp


    While Cells(linhaverif, cformula + 1).Value = "Iguais"
    cref = cref + 1
    linhaverif = linhaverif + 1
    Wend

     Next cref

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
'
'Apagar botões e pintar células
'
    Dim botoes As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
        For botoes = 1 To 200
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(botoes).Buttons.Delete
        Next botoes

        Range(Columns(ref + 5), Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```